# How do I migrate and sync up a table efficiently?

Tags: mysql

I have a table A, it has millions of records and it's growing. A new column needs be added to table A with indexing, but it could be headache to migrate such a large table. So table B is created at some point from table A, question is how to sync up these 2 tables efficiently? 
There're multiple scenarios new records will be added to table A.

Answer (score 0):

To 'Sync' up two tables without actually merging them you can create a UNION VIEW. A VIEW can be used just like a table for calculation, manipulation,  data storage etc. This is assuming that both tables have the same amount of rows, if not you'll need to create primary and foreign keys.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewname AS
   SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

Now if both tables don't share the same amount of rows you'll need at least 1 field in common between the two tables called primary and foreign keys, to join the tables using the primary and foreign keys you'll need to use a JOIN like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewname AS
SELECT TableA.FieldName, TableB.FieldName, TableA.FieldName
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.primarykeyField = TableB.foreignkeyField
UNION ALL
SELECT TableA.FieldName, TableB.FieldName, TableA.FieldName
FROM TableA
RIGHT JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.primarykeyField = TableB.foreignkeyField
```

It depends on what type of join you want but I think FULL JOIN will give you the best results, FULL JOIN's aren't supported in MySQL but using LEFT JOIN RIGHT JOIN and UNION ALL mimics the same results.

Or if you simply want to copy all the records from table A to table B you could use this.

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT * FROM TableA;
```